# Dog new at the office; should I force walks to stimulate him more?

Tags: dogs

I am dogsitting my parents dog for a period of 2 weeks (he is used to staying 1-2 days, 2 weeks is new to him) and he goes with me to the office during the day. He is a 9 year old chichuahua mix, on the 'large' side of the chihuahua scale.

Normally he would go on 2 walks a day and spend the rest of the day around the house, in the garden, interacting with my parents or their cats.

- 8:00 - A 15-20 min walk
- 15:00 - A 15-20 min walk

Currently this is our schedule:

- 8:00 - Garden time for 15 mins
- 9:00 - 10 min walk
- 12:00 - 10 min walk
- 15:30 - 10 min walk
- 18:00 - 10 min walk
- 19:00-22:00 as much garden time as he pleases

And ofcourse I play with him during the day whenever he offers me a toy or looks bored to me.

However, he seems to not enjoy the walks at all. He doesn't with my parents and he does so even less in this unknown environment.

**Should I wake him during his naps to go for a walk he seems to not really enjoy?**
Or does him saying no to the walks suggest he is stimulated enough?

Comment: What makes you feel he doesn't enjoy the walks?

Comment: @Layna Him trying to turn around, stand still or back up constantly :p He'll run directly for my car or the office entrance and will try to stay put no matter how enthusiastic I try to be.

Comment: Let the dog nap

Comment: I feel like you are taking him on too many walks. Even compared to his old schedule. Why do you feel the need to him on a walk 6 times a day? Also does he try to avoid all the walks or is it only on particular times of the day?

Comment: @Pink_NinjaTurtle he's usually ok with the morning walk, the rest he acts like this. I'm not experienced in caring for dogs, maybe I overdid it in trying to fulfilll his needs

Comment: A new environment is always very scaring. So it is generally a good idea to undertake as much habits and routines as possible from their old/normal life and to change as less as possible. He possibly will feel better with only two walks at the time he is used to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Him trying to turn around, stand still or back up constantly, He'll run directly for my car or the office entrance and will try to stay put no matter how enthusiastic I try to be.

He's definitely scared of his new environment, with this demeanor I would limit his walks outside the office. He may even appreciate staying at your place by himself while you're at work, your house is much more familiar to him.

> Should I wake him during his naps to go for a walk he seems to not really enjoy?

Let him rest - he will let you know when he needs to do his business outside. 2-3 times a day is plenty for a senior chihuahua which can be done in recognizable territory like your home.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With commute I am away from home for about 9-10 hours depending on traffic and I feel like this is way too long to leave him alone. He seems to feel pretty comfortable in the office itself, he'll mostly sleep and will go out to greet my colleagues on his own when he feels like it. He plays and eats well.

Comment: Ya 9-10 hours is a long time, glad to hear he does well inside. You can always bring a collapse-able cage with a bed inside to act as his house too (cage door open). Once a dog is familiar with a crate they treat it as their safe space.